# Using AzureDevops, a Virtual Test Server and Selenium how can I get my test script to upload a file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, azure-devops, devops

Using: Selenium, c#, Visual Studio, Azure Devops

Here's the testing scenario which works when I run the test locally:
Pre-Condition:  A folder with files exists on the computer

1. The script makes a copy of the folder and all sub-folders/content
2. The script renames the folder and some files (not really a factor in this problem)
3. The script zips up the recently created folder
4. The user now logs on to a website
5. The user enters the folder path and the zipfile  into a text box.
6. The user submits the file
   Result:  The zip file is uploaded to the system.

**Issue:**

When I place my test/solution and execute the test locally all the steps above work correctly and once the test is complete I can manually log into the website and view the uploaded file.

However when I run the test in the pipeline I receive an error message which generally means it cannot find the path/folder to the zip file.  However when I look at the error logs it seems it does not find the myObject.SendKeys(AppLocation) code.  I placed longer waits between steps just to be sure that's not the issue.

Any suggestions for troubleshooting I may be missing besides consolewritelines or object exists code?

My Sample Code

```
 string AppLocation;

 // DataSets is a folder and the targetPath is name of the zipfile.  
 AppLocation = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("DataSets" + "\\" + targetPath + ".zip");

 myObject = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("//input[@type=file]"));

 myObject.SendKeys(AppLocation);  // ERROR occurs on this line saying object doesnt exist.

 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@xas-string='SDE_OK']")).Click();
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using relative paths for your files/folders?

Comment: That's my biggest worry.  I did an output to make sure I'm checking in the correct location (using .Exists ) and the folders and files are being found.   When outputting the path I  see: D:\a\r1\a\_Automated_Test_Build\drop\Google\bin\Release\DataSets\QMBBOKJ.zip.   I only define the DataSets\zipfile.  The Path from D: to Release should be the Relative path on the Virtual Server.

Comment: If you're using azure devops then probably you will have to provide the Workspace path. This might be helpful.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/create-work-workspaces?view=azure-devops]